# how to append multiple color values in spectrum js input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

[image]

By default, if we choose one color it show is color code in input box, if we choose next it overwrite the last choosed color value. But I want to append all selected color values with comma separator. Like this #7623131,#252525,#369855. I confused whether I have to overwrite plugin function or have to write any other user defined function.

```
<h2>Basic Usage</h2>
<input type='text' class="basic"/>

$(".basic").spectrum({
color: "#f00",
showInput:true,
preferredFormat:'hex',
change: function(color) {
    $("#basic-log").text("change called: " + color.toHexString());
}
});

http://jsfiddle.net/ctkY3/5227/
```

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: yeah sure I will..

Answer (score 1):

- Use [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event
- Use [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to concatenate `items` with `delimeter`
- Use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check if new color exists in `array`

```js
var arr = [];
$('[type="color"]').on('input', function() {
  if (this.value && arr.indexOf(this.value) === -1) {
    arr.push(this.value);
    $('[type="text"]').val(arr.join(', '));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="color">
<input type="text">
```

Comment: I am not using native color type, I am using spectrum js

Comment: @hardcode — How does that make a difference ? Logic remains the same....

Comment: @hardcode — Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved the purpose :) __Happy coding!__

Comment: Rayon, It is possible to append the values in color palette textbox itself, instead of in separate element(label or textbox)

Comment: Ryon in your fiddle, you appended the values in <em> tag, but I want to append in color palette textbox itself

Comment: @hardcode — I do not think that is possible(easily). I have never used this widget. Go through the documentation and see if any option is available...

Comment: I went through documentation, they didn't provide option like this, anyway I have to override js function. thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(()=>{
  $('#Color').on('change', function() { 
     $('#txtColor').val( $('#txtColor').val()+','+ $('#Color').val());
  });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='color' id='Color' />
<input type='text'  id='txtColor'/>
```